# In-app language change with ComponentActivity main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add an in-app language changer for my application. I am using Jetpack Compose and I have tried this function:

```
fun changeLanguage(language: Languages, context: Context){
    val languageString = when(language) {
        Languages.ENGLISH -> "en"
        Languages.ITALIAN -> "it"
        Languages.FRENCH -> "fr"
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
        context.getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java).applicationLocales = LocaleList.forLanguageTags(languageString)
    }else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(languageString))
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the build version is at least tiramisu, it will work, otherwise it won't. The only solution I have found was changing the "extends" in MainActivity to AppCompatActivity. Is there any other way to do this, because if I extend to AppCompatActivity it will work, but it will change the UI.

Comment: If you are using `AppCompatDelegate` methods, those only apply to `AppCompatActivity`. What made you think it would work with `ComponentActivity`?

Comment: Yes I know, it won't work. I specified it though that I tried using AppCompatDelegate and it caused problems to the UI so I would like to stick to ComponentActivity and I have to find a "substitute" to this line of code `AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(LocaleListCompat.forLanguageTags(languageString))` that is compatible with ComponentActivity

Answer (score 0):

**For API levels below Tiramisu (let's say before Android 12):**
Use the traditional method to update the default locale configuration in your app's Context. You can use a combination of Resources.updateConfiguration and Locale to achieve this.

**For Tiramisu and above (Android 12 and later):**
Utilize the LocaleManager or LocaleList approach that you've implemented in your code.

```
fun changeLanguage(language: Languages, context: Context) {
    val languageString = when (language) {
        Languages.ENGLISH -> "en"
        Languages.ITALIAN -> "it"
        Languages.FRENCH -> "fr"
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        // Use LocaleManager for Android 12 and later
        context.getSystemService(LocaleManager::class.java).applicationLocales = LocaleList.forLanguageTags(languageString)
    } else {
        // For earlier versions, update the app's configuration manually
        val locale = Locale(languageString)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)

        val resources = context.resources
        val configuration = resources.configuration
        configuration.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

This way, you handle the language changes based on the Android version, using the appropriate method for each scenario without requiring changes in the MainActivity inheritance. Remember to call this function whenever the user changes the language preference in your app.

Comment: It works, but updateConfiguration() is deprecated.